# Android - json list view

Tags: android, json, listview, android-volley

I'm using volley for web services. So, when I run the app each time it doesn't show anything in the list. But when I use debug, sometimes I got the list correctly. So here is the code.

It's like it insert the listItem on `Listview` before getting the data from json , i tried to put a wait() before the adapter but android studio don't accept it .

Is there anyone who had similar problem ?

```
    public class listedeal_res extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.listedeal_res);
            Button ajouter=(Button) findViewById(R.id.ajouetres);
            Intent i =getIntent();
            final   ListView maListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.liste_deal_res);
            final int idres=i.getIntExtra("idres",0);
            final boolean b =true;
            ajouter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(listedeal_res.this,AjouterDeal.class);
                    intent.putExtra("idres",idres);
                    listedeal_res.this.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
           final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItem = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

          final  HashMap<String, String> map;
            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Response.Listener<String> resp=new  Response.Listener<String>()
            {           
                @Override
                public void onResponse (String response) {
                    try {       
                        JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(response);
                        int i=0;    
                        while (jsonResponse.getJSONArray(i)!=null)
                        {
                            while (jsonResponse.getJSONArray(i)!=null)
                            {
                                map.put("Nom",jsonResponse.getJSONArray(i).getString(2));
                                map.put("Restraurant",jsonResponse.getJSONArray(i).getString(0));
                                map.put("description",jsonResponse.getJSONArray(i).getString(1));
                                listItem.add(map);

                                i++;
                            }
                        }    
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            };

            drinkeat.drinkandeat.javas.liste_deal_res_req liste_deal_res_req= new liste_deal_res_req(idres+"",resp);
            RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(listedeal_res.this);
            queue.add(liste_deal_res_req );

            SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter (this.getBaseContext(), listItem, R.layout.row_deal_user,
                    new String[] {"Nom", "Restraurant", "description"}, new int[] {R.id.titlerow, R.id.resteaurantnaamerow, R.id.descriptionrow});

            maListView.setAdapter(mSchedule);

        }
    }
```

Comment: in volley on response call notifydatasetchange();   method

Comment: try to refresh your adapter after you receive data from webservice. Use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after adding new items to `ArrayList`.

Comment: i added an answer , to make it easy for you

Answer (score 0):

Add notifydatasetchange method to your adapter like below

```
 public void onResponse (String response) {
                try {       
                    JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(response);
                    int i=0;    
                    while (jsonResponse.getJSONArray(i)!=null)
                    {
                        while (jsonResponse.getJSONArray(i)!=null)
                        {
                            map.put("Nom",jsonResponse.getJSONArray(i).getString(2));
                            map.put("Restraurant",jsonResponse.getJSONArray(i).getString(0));
                            map.put("description",jsonResponse.getJSONArray(i).getString(1));
                            listItem.add(map);

                            i++;
                        }
                    } 
                     mSchedule.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

Comment: mschedule is declared after the on reponse , if i declare it before and put it as final , it still doesn"t work